# In an R pie chart, how do I rearrange the labels of each pie slice so that they are running alongside the same angle as the slices?

Tags: r

Here is my code so far:

```
variablename = c("really long label", "another really long label", "this is a long placeholder", "I need a better imagination", "Thanks in advance for your help"),
+     Freq = c(548, 326, 292, 199, 138)

variablename %>%
  mutate(perc =scales::percent(Freq/sum(Freq))) %>%
  arrange(desc(Var1)) %>%
  mutate(pos = cumsum(Freq)- Freq/2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = Freq, fill = factor(Var1) )) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(aes(x = "", y = pos, label = perc), size=5, show.legend = F, nudge_x = 1) + ggtitle("Male") +
  geom_text(aes(x = "", y = pos, label = Var1)) + theme(legend.position="none")
```

Here is the graph produced:
[image: pie chart]

As you can see, the labels for each slice overflow and overlap with the other labels. How do I rearrange the angle of each label so that they are pointing at the same angle as their slices, so that the texts don't overlap with one another? (Or at least a way to make the texts legible, but without having to make a legends tab due to specific reasons.)

Comment: Where are you viewing this? When I expand the plot in RStudio , the labels are legible and easy to read.

Comment: @Ronak Shah oh, yeah I guess. In that case, can you tell me how to shrink the labels? (Since my actual data still overflows a bit when zoomed in)